# 500 internal server is showing when server side method is call from AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My problem is that when I am call the data from AJAX to server side method in ASP.NET C# at that time in browser console showing the error i.e. 500 internal server error.

here is my code of client side,

```
 <label for="fname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="txt_name" placeholder="Your Name.."/>

    <label for="lname">EmailID</label>
    <input type="text" id="txt_emailID" placeholder="Your EmailID.."/>

    <label for="lname">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" id="txt_subject" placeholder="Your Subject.."/>

    <label for="subject">Content</label>
    <textarea id="txt_content" placeholder="Write content.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" id="submit_mail" value="Send"/>


<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#submit_mail").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "contact.aspx/SendMail",
                data: "{name: $('#txt_name').val(), email: $('#txt_emailID').val(), subject: $('#txt_subject').val(), message: $('#txt_content').val()}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }

</script>
```

and here is the code of server side

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
protected void SendMail(string name, string email, string subject, string message)
{
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that your actual C# code? Also note that the `data` you're sending is invalid. You'd be better off removing the quotes around the string, and giving jQuery an object it can serialise itself.

Comment: Yes it is actual c# code only. Can you show me the syntax of my code.

Comment: Just remove the `"` around the value you give to `data`. Then you need to actually put some logic in the C# method which generates a valid response

Comment: I have done like this                                                                                data: {name: $('#txt_name').val(), email: $('#txt_emailID').val(), subject: $('#txt_subject').val(), message: $('#txt_content').val()},                          
 but then also same issues is coming

Comment: After removing the quotation marks, you could try calling JSON.stringify on that object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebMethod` should be `public static` not `protected` as we are not calling it from same class/subclass.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static void SendMail(string name, string email, string subject, string message)
{
}
```

also try

```
data: JSON.stringify({name: $('#txt_name').val(), email: $('#txt_emailID').val(), subject: $('#txt_subject').val(), message: $('#txt_content').val()}),
```

instead of plain string.

Comment: I have changed from protected to public but then also same error is coming.

Comment: pleased to help

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Please try without parameter as per below

```
     [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    protected void SendMail()
    {
    }
```

And remove line from ajax  : `data: "{name: $('#txt_name').val(), email: $('#txt_emailID').val(), subject: $('#txt_subject').val(), message: $('#txt_content').val()}",`

Please try step 1 and check still error coming or not .

step 2 : Update (protected to public static)

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static void SendMail()
{
}
```

step 3 :

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static void SendMail(string name)
    {
    }
```

and update add `data: "{name: $('#txt_name').val()}"` in ajax call check now

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you convert 
**SendMail(string name, string email, string subject, string message)**
 into SendMail(Email email)

```
class Email 
{
    string name;
    string email;
    string subject;
    string message;
}
```

Comment: but the call is not coming in sendmail method after going ajax only it shows the internal error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add script manager control to your page, only after adding it web method call can execute.